# ADLDS USER MANAGMENT

Tags: configuration, adlds

I have created an ADLDS Instance for an asp.net application to create/Maintain user objects.

```
CN=CN=UserInstance,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=Com
  +CN=Lostandfound
  +CN=NTDSQuots
  +CN=Roles
  +CN=UserS
  +CN=TESTUSER
```

when i create a user from application it is creating in root instead of should create inside the "Users" Container in the mentioned image.

"LDAP://localhost:7389/CN=UserInstance,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=Com"

Please assist how to make configuration so that when user is created it should create inside the "Users" Container instead of in root

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution ,

In my LDAP Connection string i need to add the container name which i need to insert the users.and need to put create my ADAM Administrator inside that container.Reset it works smoothly